# RequireJS setting Module variables from outside doesnt take effect

Tags: javascript, requirejs, js-amd, module-pattern

Im having trouble setting variables within a requireJS Define module, it flatout doesnt take effect. I have the following (cutdown) example to illustrate the issue:

Here is the defined module:

```
define([], function () {
var testerString = "BaseLine";

var ShowTesterString = function () {
    console.log(testerString);
}

var setTesterString = function (pTesterString) {
    testerString = pTesterString;
}

return {
    testerString: testerString,
    ShowTesterString: ShowTesterString,
    setTesterString: setTesterString
};  
});
```

I than set the "TesterModule" as a dependency of another and run the following lines of code:

```
TesterModule.ShowTesterString();
TesterModule.testerString = "Change 1";
TesterModule.ShowTesterString();
TesterModule.setTesterString("Change in Setter");
TesterModule.ShowTesterString();
```

What gets outputted to the console is:

```
BaseLine 
BaseLine 
Change in Setter
```

I would have thought that it should be :

```
BaseLine 
Change 1
Change in Setter
```

It seems that setting a variable in a module just by doing variable = blah doesnt take any effect, it seems to require to set variables within a method of the module. Can anyone explain to me why this is? Or what I am coding wrong?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I can tell, not being super-familiar with RequireJS, this is a pure-JavaScript problem. Change

```
console.log(testerString);
// to
console.log(this.testerString);
```

and change

```
testerString = pTesterString;
// to
this.testerString = pTesterString;
```

so that you're getting/setting the value in the object returned by the anonymous function, rather than closing over the `var testerString` variable. What's happening in your code currently may be clarified if you use variable names that differ from the returned object keys:

```
define([], function () {
    var foo = "BaseLine";

    var ShowTesterString = function () {
        console.log(foo);
    }

    var setTesterString = function (pTesterString) {
        foo = pTesterString;
    }

    return {
        testerString: foo,
        ShowTesterString: ShowTesterString,
        setTesterString: setTesterString
    };  
});
```

Also, as [a matter of style](http://jslint.com), it's better to use a "normal" function declaration:

```
function ShowTesterString () {
    ...
}
```

than to use `var ShowTesterString = function () { ... }`, as in your code.

Comment: Hi Matt, Thanks for your response. Ive changed define function to the layout you suggested but it didnt make a difference. So Im wondering if it something to do with RequireJS AMD style under the hood. Any other ideas?

Comment: You changed your code to use `foo`? That was just an example to clarify _why_ it's not working, not solve the problem. The solve is to use `this.testerString` as in the partial snippets.